# read assembly file in C

Tags: c, parsing, assembly, mips

I have a project that I have to make a parser in C (first milestone) that it read an assembly file, e.g

```
goto:

goto: 

L.D F0,0(R1) #### comments 

ADD.D F4,F0,F2 #### more comments

S.D 0(R1),F4  ###

DSUBUI R1,R1,8 ####

BNEZ R1,goto 
L.D F0 0X00A0100
```

MAYBE 10000 instructions (after that...)

I am thinking of doing this by using arrays....is there a better way of doing this?  Also I have to simulate [Tomasulo's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo_algorithm) using the commands I read from the file.

Comment: "Using arrays"? Yes, arrays will be *some* part of your solution. So will loops, variables, conditionals and other fundamental software building blocks, but you can't parse a file "using arrays". What exactly are you asking, if you should store the parsed statements in an array? As it stands, there is no way to answer your question because it doesn't make any sense. The better way than "using arrays" would be to *write a parser*.

Comment: How did this question get an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unlikely to get much help here with such a general question.

There are existing MIPS assemblers that do parsing which might provide you with some ideas, or at least some better questions:

http://code.google.com/p/mips-assembler-unb/source/browse/trunk/src/MIPS+Assembler/

...but clearly you'll be setting yourself up for a world of pain if you try using anything like that directly for a class project!

The best source for guidance if you're going to be graded will come from the person who's going to end up giving out the grade.  Admit your confusion and ask for help directly.  But go with a very clear map of what you *did* understand, and the point where your understanding stopped.

*(This question doesn't demonstrate that kind of clarity, and your teacher will probably be unenthusiastic—much like the community here—if you put it to them in the same way.)*

Comment: ok thanks but i need the source code for the parser in C.. generally i have to do my own parser reading a file with assembly instructions like in the example and i don't know how i will implement this in C.. that's way i need your help..i know i have to use Structs in C..but i also have those comments and the addresses and i don't know how to do this..and if i don't make this until 10/10/2012 i will cut from the lesson..